# form regular expresion for diff

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to make a regular expression to match the following pattern string below:

```
@@ -0,0 +1,42 @@
```

The `@@` are always at the start and end, the only thing that changes is whats in between them. Below list of examples:

```
@@ -31,9 +31,14 @@
@@ -13,9 +13,9 @@ 
@@ -4,3 +4,6 @@
```

Comment: so your regex works then?  if not what's the issue with it

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "this regex is going to be used to split a string". Give an example of the string, and the result of the corrcct splitting of that string

Comment: `input = input.replaceFirst("@{2}(.*?)@{2}", "$1");`

Comment: With the anchors `^$`, I cannot imagine that the regex is able to split a longer string, which implies that there will be otehr things around...

Comment: What is the problem with your current solution?

Comment: My solution was splitting "@@" but that leave what's in between the "@@"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, then something like this would be a simple solution:

```
String s = "@@ -31,9 +31,14 @@" + '\n' +
           "something" + '\n' +
           "@@ -13,9 +13,9 @@"  + '\n' +
           "@@ -4,3 +4,6 @@";
String[] items = s.split("[\\s]*@@[^(@@).^(@@)]*@@[\\s]*");
```

Output:

```
something
```

Comment: No becuase that would leave me with whats contained in the middle and that something I dont want to have also.

Comment: The content in between is generated randomly

Comment: No problem. This solution works also for randomly generated content between @@ and @@. It matches for `@@<randomly generated content between>@@` Maybe this can also help you understanding regex: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html